# Do applied papers introduce new notation for every regression?

Tags: econometrics

I am currently writing an empirical paper which reports on the results from estimating a number of regression models.

Question: is it standard to introduce new notation for each of these models, or should one stick to $\beta_0$, $\beta_1$, etc. every time? I am trying not to re-use notation but am running out of Greek letters...

NB I do realise that this is not a question about economics *per se* and do apologise for this in advance!

Comment: This is probably better fit for academia.se. This being said I was always taught that within single paper if you use more than 1 model you should introduce new notation because the same letter should not refer to 2 different coefficients if those coefficients are not same. However, if you dislike using different letters you could just add an equation specific subscript. You can also use Latin letters, e.g. $b_0$ $b_1$.

Comment: @1muflon1 : I can't see this at academia.se, but stats.se seems like a good fit.